# KCFinder + TinyMCE Integration

Tags: image, tinymce, file-management

It seems that I integrated KCFinder to TinyMCE quite successfully. The only problem is when the file manager popups and I want to select a picture, it doesn't have neither Select nor Select Thumbnail on the menu (the menu appears when a picture is right-clicked). A little bit of help please.

Here is a [screenshot](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53622932/stackoverflow_tinymce_kcfinder_no_select.png) of KCFinder